# SQLite MATCH query

Tags: sqlite

I have created a virtual table and am executing the following query that returns nothing:

```
SELECT * FROM table_search WHERE name MATCH 'Test'
```

If I change the MATCH to '=' or 'LIKE' then the query returns a row of data.

Comment: Show the table creation statement, and an example record that you think should match.

Comment: I've solved it now by using fts3 instead of fts4. Not sure why it wouldn't work in fts4 as LIKE and = both worked.

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) explains:

> The `MATCH` operator is a special syntax for the match()
>   application-defined function. The default match() function
>   implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for
>   anything. But extensions can override the match() function with more
>   helpful logic.

If you haven't defined such a function, then it will select no rows.  If you have defined such a function, then explain that in your question.  Otherwise, stick with `like`, `=`, or `regexp`.

Comment: I've created the virtual tables for FTS searches in Android, I though the whole point was to use MATCH?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering what changed since Gordon Linoff's answer, because he is obviously quite the SQL expert and I'm not. Just talking about my own experience:

Don't specify the column but the table name for FTS queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table_search WHERE table_search MATCH 'Test'
```

I did the same mistake and even tried the implementation of a custom `MATCH` function from [this repository](https://github.com/njamescouk/matchExtension) after reading the answer from Gordon Linoff and the [doc](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators).

> The MATCH operator is a special syntax for the match() application-defined function. The default match() function implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for anything. But extensions can override the match() function with more helpful logic.

Contrary, I found out the `MATCH` function works out of box (using sqlite 3.39) if I used the table name, and an asterix `'Test*'` but that was just because of my specific dataset and a wrong assumption.

The custom function is not being called by the `MATCH`, but it is called if I applied it to a column like

```
SELECT match(name) FROM table_search WHERE table_search MATCH 'Test'
```

which is a very different intention.